# How to put IF statement in given scenario?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner programmer Java:
I want to get 10 values from user and put if statement, if some one enters grade value above 100, it may get "Enter right value < 100"
But i don't want to use any array etc.
When i use the following code, it shows the error message but for 1 wrong value, it calculates other 09 values and don't repeat the wrong value, given if statement skips the wrong

```
int i, number, total=0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (i=1; i<=10; i++)
        {   System.out.print("Enter Grade "+i+" : \n");
                number = sc.nextInt();
                if (number < 100);;
                {total = total + number;}
        }
```

Comment: just put a check when user enter values, and show error if value greater then 100. so you dont have to calculate all values..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    int number, total=0;
    int i = 1;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (i<=10)
    {   
          System.out.print("Enter Grade "+i+" : \n");
          number = sc.nextInt();
          if (number < 100){
               total = total + number;
               i++;
          }else{
                 System.out.println("invalid value");
          }
    }
```

This will work, using a while loop

Comment: @Tom so that if you enter an invalid value, it will keep on looping. It allows for more control

Comment: Well ok, instead of decrementing `i` in the `else` branch (with a `for` loop), you're incrementing it in the `if` branch. Ok, point taken.

Answer (score 0):

You just had few typo errors in your code also , to make the for loop more simple you don't need to define i at top just define the i when you need to use the for loop . And its avoid overwrite outside of the for loop .
To make using for loop more professional also considering that maybe sometimes you need to use it for arrays its better to always start the loop with i=0 thats the better practice.
After if(condition) don't need to put any ;

```
int  number, total=0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i=1; i<=10; i++)
    {   System.out.print("Enter Grade "+i+" : \n");
        number = sc.nextInt();
        if (number < 100){
            total = total + number;
        }
    }
```